# Error with networking : Windows has detected an IP address conflict error?

Tags: windows, networking, ip-address

I'm puzzled by what this error means :

[image]

But my program(lotus notes) , still works fine.  I just want to know what that entails, an "IP address conflict error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that there is more than a single device with the same IP address in your network. This usually happens when using static IPs without DHCP server to provide them (i.e., setting the IP manually). This can lead to multiple connectivity issues since the address is not unique now, creating an inherent ambiguity for the routing protocol. The system may appear working but this isn't something to rely on since this is a serious problem that should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious about what `creating an inherent ambiguity for the routing protocol` can lead to. I will study up more on DHCP and static IP. Thank you

Comment: @Coffee Routing protocol basically propagates packets over the network from source to destination. Source and destination are identified by their IPs. Non-unique IP leads to the lack of possibility of exact source/target identification.